# How does an array in swift deep copy itself when copied or assigned

Tags: swift

We all know an array in swift is a value type, this means after copying or assigning an array to another, modify the new array will not effect the old one. Such as:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var b = a
b[0] = "1"
print(a[0]) // a
print(b[0]) // 1
```

But I'm wondering how could an array work like that. The length for a 'var' array is dynamical. Usually we must alloc some heap memory to contain all  the values. And I do peek some source codes for struct Array, the underlining buffer for an array is implemented using a class. But when copying a struct which contains class or memory pointer member, the class and alloced memory will not copied by default.

So how could an array copy its buffer when copy or assign it to another one?

Comment: The "copy-on-write optimization“ is mentioned in the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Comment: See also https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html.

Comment: @MartinR Greate article, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment of any `struct` (such as `Array`) causes a shallow copy of the structure contents. There's no special behavior for `Array`. The buffer that stores the `Array`'s elements is not actually part of the structure. A pointer to that buffer, stored on the heap, *is* part of the `Array` structure, meaning that upon assignment, the buffer pointer is copied, but it still points to the same buffer.

All mutating operations on `Array` do a check to see if the buffer is uniquely referenced. If so, then the algorithm proceeds. Otherwise, a copy of the buffer is made, and the pointer to the new buffer is saved to that `Array` instance, then the algorithm proceeds as previously. This is called Copy on Write (CoW). Notice that it's not an automatic feature of all value types. It is merely a manually implemented feature of a few standard library types (like `Array`, `Set`, `Dictionary`, `String`, and others). You could even implement it yourself for your own types.

When CoW occurs, it does *not* do any deep copying. It will copy values, which means:

- In the case of value types (`struct`, `enum`, tuples), the values are the `struct`/`enum`/tuples themselves. In this case, a deep and shallow copy are the same thing.
- In the case of reference types (`class`), the value being copied is the *reference*. The *referenced object* is not copied. The same object is pointed to by both the old and copied reference. Thus, it's a shallow copy.

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but highly compiler specific. In Swift 4.2, structs generally seem to be optimized in this way, but older versions always copied the structs and you had to implement that copy-on-write on your own it you wanted it.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen That's still the case. Copy-on-write is a "manually implemented" feature of `Array` that's not generic to all `struct`. Ah, I see I was kinda unclear. Fixing it now

Comment: Should the function ```isKnownUniquelyReferenced``` be used to implement the copy-on-write feature? Or is there any other better one to check if the reference is unique?

Comment: @NewSelf It's the only one I know of. Do you find it somehow insufficient?